# How do i generate a random integer with increment being only of 100's -- C#

Tags: c#

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next()
```

How do I set output random integers with increments being only in 100's?

Comment: I'm sure a simple search will give you the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can take a random number from 0 through 9 (I'm assuming you want something between 100 and 900) and then multiply the result by 100.

```
var num = random.Next(10) * 100;
```